# Applescript clicking unknown menu item?

Tags: macos, menu, applescript, automator

I'm using the **LG OnScreen Control** app to switch between different monitor layouts which have no names in the menu item as it uses pictures. I want to write an applescript that clicks either the first one or the 9th one, my favourite selections. =)

[image]

**How can I click them?** I only managed to select them with the below code

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "OnScreen Control"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end ignoring
delay 0.1
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "OnScreen Control"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click menu item "Screen Split" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

**UPDATE1:** Ah silly me, I figured I can use "key code 125" several times to click the down arrow and "key code 76" to hit enter.

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "OnScreen Control"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end ignoring
delay 0.1
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "OnScreen Control"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click menu item "Screen Split" of menu 1
        key code 125
        key code 125
        key code 125
        key code 125
        key code 125
        key code 125
        key code 125
        key code 125
        key code 76
    end tell
end tell
```

**Wondering though if there is a better and quicker way to execute this? Addressing the sub-items directly despite not having a name?**

**UDPATE2** with solution thanks to @user3439894

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "OnScreen Control"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end ignoring
delay 0.1
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "OnScreen Control"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click menu item "Screen Split" of menu 1
        click menu item 9 of menu 1 of menu item "Screen Split" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Comment: Ah silly me, I figured I can use "key code 76". Wondering if there is a better and quicker way to execute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

```
click menu item "Screen Split" of menu 1
```

Use:

```
click menu item 9 of menu 1 of menu item "Screen Split" of menu 1
```

Getting rid of all the `key code` *commands*

Comment: Nice, thanks that worked! learning the menu of menu combinations is tricky. =) 
I wish there is a way to do the same without the delays and visually seeing the actions. Might you know if this is possible? (might open another question but curious)

Comment: RE: "I wish there is a way to do the same without the delays" see my answer to [A: AppleScript - Can't get rid of delay after click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423354/applescript-cant-get-rid-of-delay-after-click/423440?r=SearchResults&s=1|18.9520#423440) for how the _delay_ can be handled. -- RE: "and visually seeing the actions. Might you know if this is possible?" --  Not having a LG monitor I cannot say, however, I'd look to see if it writes to a **.plist** _file_ and then see about manipulating it with either the `defaults` _command_ or `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` _command_.

Comment: @Markus, see by comment above, thanks.

Comment: Great thanks, I already tried using the **kill and delay method**. I left out the second delay as it didn't seem to make much of a difference (without the first one before do shell it wouldn't even run). I really like your explanation though, the answer is so well written, awesome I learned some more and gave you a voteup. Just wondering if you found the clickclick (or mousetools) to be faster than AppleScript? I'm assuming applescript is still best here.

Comment: Thanks also for the tip re .plist file. I only found one in the app content (none in library folder) which doesn't look like it's storing these settings and the file doesn't change while selecting different layouts. I'm assuming this function is handled via software to snap the windows to these layouts thus .plist would only work if the function would be handled by the hardware of the monitor.